# Workaround/resolution for Swift compiler error related to Void callback defined in struct

Tags: xcode, swift, generics

Due to the lack of generic support in `typealias` definitions in Swift, I wrote a generic `ResultHandler<T>` callback like so:

```
struct ResultHandler<T> {
    let f: (result: T) -> ()
}
```

This works great for handlers that use anything other than `Void`:

```
Dispatch<Bool>.dispatch({ () -> (Result<Bool>) in
    Result<Bool>(true)
}).onResult(ResultHandler() { (result: Bool) in
    if result {
        self.doSomething() // Method executes successfully
    }
})
```

But when attempting to use `Void`:

```
Dispatch<Void>.dispatch({ () -> (Result<Void>) in
    Result<Void>()
}).onResult(ResultHandler() { (result: Void) in // Compiler error here
    self.doSomething()
})
```

There is a compilation error:

> Function signature '(Void) -> ()' is not compatible with expected type
>   '(result: Void) -> ()'

Which seems *misleading/a compiler bug*, as if I change the signature to use a wrongly-typed value:

```
Dispatch<Void>.dispatch({ () -> (Result<Void>) in
    Result<Void>()
}).onResult(ResultHandler() { (result: Void?) in // Compiler error here
    self.doSomething()
})
```

The error message picks up the optional-indicating `?`, but still does not properly detect my `result:` label:

> Function signature '(Void?) -> ()' is not compatible with expected type
>   '(result: Void) -> ()'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify parameter names in closure type declarations—that's what's giving the compiler problems:

```
struct ResultHandler<T> {
    let f: T -> ()
}
```

Now you can create `ResultHandler` instances that use a `Bool` parameter, a `Void` parameter, or leave out the parameter altogether:

```
let r1 = ResultHandler() { (result: Bool) in
    if result {
        // do something
    }
}

let r2 = ResultHandler() { (_: Void) in
    // do something
}

let r3 = ResultHandler() {
    // do something
}
```