# Swift 1.2 - Error caused by closure parameters of a class function

Tags: ios, swift, closures

Since I upgraded to Swift 1.2, I have this weird problem, that I cannot resolve. Here is the code that causes all the trouble:

```
internal class Test<T,U> {
    internal class func closureFunc(#arg: T, worker: (first: T, second: String) -> U, closure: ((u: U) -> Void)?) -> Void {
        println("Something")
    }
}
Test.closureFunc(arg: "", worker: { (first, second) -> Void in
    //code
    }) { (u) -> Void in
    //code
}
```

The error itself says:

> "Function signature (Void) -> Void is not compatible with expected type (u: Void) -> Void".

I read all about Swift 1.2 and I still can't seem to find a reasonable explanation for this. I will be extremely thankful for any tips and suggestions.

PS: I just saw [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560794/workaround-resolution-for-swift-compiler-error-related-to-void-callback-defined), that is similar to mine but removing the parameter name in the closure didn't quite work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Swift 1.2 (and even Swift 2 (Xcode 7 beta 3)) with single parameter closures with external names.

As workaround you can remove the external parameter name "u":

```
internal class func closureFunc(#arg: T, worker: (first: T, second: String) -> U, closure: (U -> Void)?) -> Void
```

in Swift 2 (only) there is another workaround where you can give the passed closure an external name (since this would conform to the new and more strict naming conventions):

```
Test.closureFunc(arg: "", worker: { (first, second) -> Void in
    //code
    }) { (anyExternalNameWorks u: Void) -> Void in
    //code
}
```